# Print values from MongoDB collection with Multi level array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

The requirement i got is to flatten the document with multi level array in MongoDB collection, and print it in a row to export to text file. Here is the sample data:

```
db.multiLevelArray.insertMany([{ "field1" : "value 1",
    "field2": [{ field3: "value 3"
                , field4: [{ field5: "value 5"
                            , field6: "value 6"
                            },{field5: "value 55"
                            , field6: "value 66"
                            }]
                , field7: "value 7"
                },
                { field3: "value 23"
                , field4: [{ field5: "value 25"
                            , field6: "value 26"
                            },{field5: "value 255"
                            , field6: "value 266"
                            }]
                , field7: "value 27"
                }
    ]
, field8: "value 8"
},{ "field1" : "value b1",
    "field2": [{ field3: "value b3"
                , field4: [{ field5: "value b5"
                            , field6: "value b6"
                            },{field5: "value b55"
                            , field6: "value b66"
                            }]
                , field7: "value b7"
                },
                { field3: "value b23"
                , field4: [{ field5: "value b25"
                            , field6: "value b26"
                            },{field5: "value b255"
                            , field6: "value b266"
                            }]
                , field7: "value b27"
                }
    ]
, field8: "value b8"
}]);
```

and here is the required output:

```
field1      field3      field5      field6    field7    field8
--------------------------------------------------------------
value 1     value 3     value 5     value 6   value 7   value8
value 1     value 3     value 55    value 56  value 7   value8
value 1     value 3     value 25    value 26  value 7   value8
value 1     value 3     value 255   value 256 value 7   value8
```

I'm new to MongoDB and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to make the proper format your data using this query, and output is saved a new collection as newMultiLevelArray by using [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)

```
db.multiLevelArray.aggregate([ {"$match" : {"field1" : "value 1"}},
                           {"$unwind" : "$field2"},
                           {"$unwind" : "$field2.field4"},
                           {"$group" : {"_id" : null,
                               "data" : 
                               {"$push" : 
                                    {
                                        "field1" : "$field1",
                                        "field3" : "$field2.field3",
                                        "field5" : "$field2.field4.field5",
                                        "field6" : "$field2.field4.field6",
                                        "field7" : "$field2.field7",
                                        "field8" : "$field8"
                                    }
                                   }
                               }
                           },
                           {"$project" : {"_id" : 0}},
                           {"$unwind" : "$data"},
                           {"$out" : "newMultiLevelArray"}
                           ])
```

Now you export your new collection what format you want by using [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection new_col_name(newMultiLevelArray) --type csv --fields data.field1,data.field3,data.field6,data.field7,data.field8 --out out_file.csv
```

sample output

[image: output-image]

Comment: Thanks for this help. very much appreciated. It works great. Is there any tool available to get such exports easily for non-developers like Analyst and Business users who got access to DB and query the data?

Comment: A lot of tools are available for MongoDB check this link https://www.guru99.com/top-20-mongodb-tools.html

Comment: my suggestion is Robo Mongo.

Comment: Thanks again Senthur Deva.